# Why is the last element of the list not shuffled in the Fischer-Yates algorithm?

Tags: shuffle

On the Wikipedia, it gives the amended Fischer-Yates shuffle algorithm as:

```
-- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
for i from 0 to n−2 do
     j ← random integer such that i ≤ j < n
     exchange a[i] and a[j]
```

Why is the last element of the array not shuffled?

Comment: If `i == n-1`, then it can only possibly be swapped with `j = n-1` so why bother running an extra iteration?

Comment: @CollinD In that case, wouldn't there be a higher probability of the last element not getting swapped, therefore a bias? In other words, there would be a 100% of 0 to n-2 being swapped, but the probability of n-1 being swapped with something is less than 100%, so it would be more likely to remain in place than the other elements. Is that true?

Comment: There is not a 100% chance of other elements being swapped, as at a given `i`, there is a `1/(n-i)` chance to swap with any element in `[i, n)` (including `i` itself).

Comment: @CollinD Right, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Putting @CollinD's comments as an answer:

If `i == n-1`, then it can only possibly be swapped with `j = n-1` so why bother running an extra iteration?

At a given `i`, there is a `1/(n-i)` chance to swap with any element in `[i, n)` (including `i` itself)